# Eclipse - Android not auto-generating R class

Tags: android, eclipse

have an odd one..

Using Eclipse Juno, and everything was working fine for the last couple months. At some point yesterday, while Eclipse was cleaning my project, something crashed - popped up the Windows error reporting. (Didn't catch the name of what crashed..)

Now, I have no R.java class in /gen, and nothing I've tried will generate it. On top of that, when doing a clean rebuild of the project, the Output window remains blank. (No errors, no status message.. nothing.)

Tried just about everything - including the latest which included reinstalling Eclipse and then ADT. Still hadn't helped. (I have NOT tried clearing the workspace metadata yet, will do that soon.)

Any thoughts on what else to check?

--Fox.

**Edit:** Updating a random file - either .java or an XML layout/drawable does not have any effect, still nothing. Also, removing saved preferences from workspace .metdata data didn't have an effect either.

**Edit 2:** Okay - not sure WHY it was happening, but creating a new project and the issue was corrected.

So somehow either the project settings (.settings or project.settings) must have gotten corrupted. I have the origianl project still, and am curious to see why it happened, but creating a new project and copying sources and resources over, and no more issue.

Thanks to all that offered comments - goes to show that any kind of little corruption can cause strange things to happen.

Comment: eclipse sometimes has this problem, suggestion modify some code or some xml files and save and make it auto rebuild.

Comment: Tried that - no change. Also tried 'fixing project properties' under Android Tools. (Updated main post.)

Comment: you try remove the `gen` folder, and rebuild?

Comment: Good thought. Just tried it - the folder gets recreated almost immediately, and doing a clean rebuild offers the same result. Java's getting compiled, or trying to, but then failes on errors saying R.java's missing. Still no logs in the Console.

Comment: -):, so you say you try new eclipse and new adt? if not, try, and suggestion create a new project to check the R.java created or not.

Comment: Yeah - now that works. Deleting /gen/ gives me the error: [2012-01-10 21:06:28 - Benchtest] R.java was removed! Recreating R.java!
So, oddly, it's something to do with project settings.

Comment: I was having the same problem and tried everything .... the problem was that I hadnt downloaded the latest Android SDK build-tools ... so open the SDK manager and update to the latest

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason in 99% of the cases is that you are missspelling something in some xml file.
The R class file won't appear until all xml files are correct.

I suggest look carefully into your XMLs for a very small syntax error.

Or try taking off 1 by 1, until you figure it out wich one is the problematic.

:) kind of annoying, i know.

Comment: I'm marking yours as the answer, as in 99.99% of the time this is the cause (and have run into issues often.

In this case, the issue appeared to be a corrupted project file from Eclipse, as simply creating a new project base and copying code over corrected the issue. (Virus Scan or something got into the way there, I'm guessing.)

Comment: my problem is use a image named default.png. rename it to splash.png solve this problem. It seems several reserved words can't be used as resource id.

Comment: I was having the same problem and tried everything .... the problem was that I hadnt downloaded the latest Android SDK build-tools ... so open the SDK manager and update to the latest

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have any errors in your xml files, you tried to reboot your eclipse, your emulator, then **open the sdk manager and apply all update**. My R have finally been generated.

Comment: Thank you sir, +1. After searching and just finding a ton of answers saying that I had type-o's in my XML files, which I didn't, I finally found your answer and sure enough I guess the last time I ran the SDK manager update it failed somehow. Updating again fixed my R file not being generate. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this happened after updating my Android SDK Manager and related eclipse plugins. I am running in Ubuntu, and it would not let me update the plugins unless I ran as the root user (using "`sudo eclipse`")

This left some of the Android SDK Manager items, and the eclipse plugins, owned by root. This stopped the "clean" working on the project - it must have been something that had been added as the root user, and not accessible as my normal user.

I had to "chown" my eclipse directory and my Android SDK Manager directory so it was owned again by my normal user:

```
cd /home/myacct/android-sdk/
chown -R myacct:myacct *
```

After this the clean option worked, and R was regenerated.

Comment: Above command says: chown: missing operand after ‘myacct:myacct’

Comment: I have corrected the chown example - thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 0):

This was it for me:
In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, make sure that you have the SDK installed for the version number in `android:minSdkVersion="##"`.

You can install SDKs from the Android SDK Manager, found under Window -> Android SDK Manager in Eclipse / ADT.

Answer (score 0):

For me it ended up being gen/com/(appname)/R.java missing.
Not in my recycle bin, not anywhere... just took a surprise vacation and never returned.

I had a backup copy in a different folder. Copied it back and all's good now