# leaderboard_id cannot be resolved or is not a field error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

In my androidlauncher.java I am getting this error :

**Multiple markers at this line**

**- leaderboard_id cannot be resolved or is not a field**

**- string cannot be resolved or is not a field**

```
    @Override
    public void submitScore(long score) {
        if (isSignedIn() == true) {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(_gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                    getString(R.String.leaderboard_id), score);
        } else {
            // signIn();
        }
    }

@Override
```

I have done the suggestions of changing :string" to "String" and adding an R.java and no luck. It was originally an issue with the "R.String"" until that was added. I am new to this. I am using eclipse. Thanks.

My **R.java**-

```
public class R {

    public static Object String;
```

Answer (score 0):

R class is automatically generated from XML resource files, and you should keep your string literals there. [Here you can find an explanation how to handle them properly](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html). Basically, you should have a file called `res/values/strings.xml` in your project containing your strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="leaderboard_id">Insert your text here.</string>
</resources>
```

And now you can extract it with:

```
String leaderboardId = getString(R.string.leaderboard_id);
```

If you are new to Android programming, I would highly recommend you [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html) instead of Eclipse, which can [have trouble generating R class if your XML files have misspelling errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8813972/5922757). [Here](https://www.airpair.com/android/android-studio-vs-eclipse) is all you need to know about the differences between these IDEs.

As for R.java, please, don't do things like `public static Object String;`. `String` is a built-in java type, and what you're doing is shadowing one of the most basic class name with member variable name.